# What does “eher” mean in “nicht eher zu ruhen”?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does “eher” mean in the following sentence?

> Er leistete einen Schwur, nicht eher zu ruhen, bis er dem Geheimnis
>   auf die Spur käme.

Comment: Was sagt das Wöterbuch?

Comment: @userunknown Wenn ich mir http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/eher so ansehe: tatsächlich nichts, was unmittelbar zur Erleuchtung führen sollte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it means "not until/before" ([e.g. see here](http://www.dict.cc/?s=nicht%20eher)): "... not to rest until he ..."

Comment: I see in dictionary that "nicht eher als" means "not until" but this sentence lacks "als".

Comment: The role of "als" is played by "bis" in the above sentence. The absence of "als" does look a bit ungrammatical to me.